# Ignoring text in worksheet when importing to python

Tags: excel, csv, python-3.x

My goal is to be able to have any excel spreadsheet (that I will save as a .cvs), and read it in python. I know how to extract the data and so far my code is this...

```
    file = input("insert csv file name to upload: ")
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    # opens any csv file if input is correct with .csv extention    

        x = []
        y = []

        for row in readCSV:                 
            x_values = row[0]
            y_values = row[1]

            x.append(x_values)
            y.append(y_values)

    X = x[1:]                               # gets rid of first line(title)
    Y = y[1:]

    X = [float(i) for i in X]
    Y = [float(i) for i in Y]
```

So this is fine in excel if the data is in the nice format of first row = "title" and the rest are values. But how can I filter through the whole thing and ignore any text?

I tried .isdigit(), but I ran into problems there when floats were introduced.

Comment: found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float-in-python) with an excellent replacement of .isdigit()

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the spreadsheet is actually numbers (and not text), then you could use [the xlrd package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) to work directly with the `.xls` file and check the data type of each cell.